# spring, how to get time from InfluxDB in Long

Tags: java, spring-boot, influxdb

I have this class-repository:

```
@Repository
public class InfluxHostAvailabilityRepository implements HostAvailabilityRepository {

    public static final String CAMERAS_DATABASE = "cameras";
    public static final String CAMERAS_PHOTOS_TABLE = "cameras_photos-count";
    private final InfluxDBMapper influxDBMapper;

    public InfluxHostAvailabilityRepository(
        @Value("${spring.influx.url}") String url,
        @Value("${spring.influx.user}") String user,
        @Value("${spring.influx.password}") String password,
        @Value("${application.availability-report.influx.read-timeout-in-seconds}") Long readTimeoutInSeconds
    ) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(readTimeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            this.influxDBMapper = new InfluxDBMapper(InfluxDBFactory.connect(url, user, password, client));
    }

    @Override
    public List<HostAvailability> getHostAvailabilityForPeriod(Instant from, Instant to,
                                                               List<String> hosts,
                                                               Integer groupByMinute,
                                                               ZoneId zone) {

        final WhereNested<?> andNested = QueryBuilder.select().count("value").as("working")
            .from(CAMERAS_DATABASE, CAMERAS_PHOTOS_TABLE)
            .where(QueryBuilder.gte("time", from.toString()))
            .and(QueryBuilder.lt("time", to.toString())).andNested();

        hosts.forEach(host -> andNested.or(QueryBuilder.eq("host", host)));

        final Query query = andNested.close()
            .groupBy("host", QueryBuilder.time(Long.valueOf(groupByMinute), DurationLiteral.MINUTE))
            .fill(0)
            .tz(zone.getId());

        log.debug("Query to influxDB: " + query.getCommand());

        return influxDBMapper.query(query, HostAvailability.class);
    }
```

and get List Objects:

```
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Measurement(name = "cameras_photos-count", timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class HostAvailability {

    /**
     * Время начала периода.
     */
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Instant intervalFrom;

    /**
     * working = 0  - считаем что хост недоступен.
     *  working > 0 - считаем что доступен
     */
    @Column(name = "working")
    private Integer working;

    /**
     * имя хоста из тега host, оно же серийный номер камеры.
     */
    @Column(name = "host")
    private String host;
}
```

with a large number of Host Availability objects, I get OutOfMemory because of the Instant type in the intervalFrom field, I want to replace this field with the Long type so as not to store Instant, I get a ClassCastException, cannot convert the String type to Long, how would I convert the time to milliseconds when requesting select so that when mapping, I immediately write to the Long field?

can you show me how to getHostAvailabilityForPeriod please?

its my dependency:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
        </dependency>
```